# Apollo HttpLink Async

Tags: asynchronous, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

For the following code:

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: endpoint,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
});
```

I need to get `endpoint` and `token` asynchronously. How may I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Are they going to be changed constantly or just once after you figure out what the endpoint/token are?

Comment: @zero298 they should not change constantly, no. The values from from an Auth0 `idToken` claim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [apollo-link-context](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/context) to modify your requests. You can cache the values as shown if you don't fetch them on every request.

```
let token
let uri
const contextLink = setContext(async () => {
  if (!token) {
    token = await getTokenAsync()
  }
  if (!uri) {
    uri = await getUriAsync()
  }

  return { uri, token }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  ...
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    contextLink,
    httpLink,
  ])
})
```

The above is the preferred way of dynamically setting these parameters. Alternatively, you could just fetch the token and URI before rendering your ApolloProvider and then dynamically create your client instance based on the values.

Comment: Would it be better to just recreate the entire client whenever the URI needs to change?  Can ApolloProvider's client be dynamic?

Comment: That's exactly what I suggest as the alternative. But this requires the logic for fetching the URI and token to reside further up the component tree, which may not always be desirable. Using `setContext` is the standard approach for setting these values dynamically.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRearden -- does this change if I'm using Apollo Client v3 (beta)?

Comment: So then I would pass `contextLink` above to `link` in my code instead of creating an `HttpLink`?

Comment: @Sammy `setContext` does not replace your `HttpLink`. You should compose your links [as shown in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/api/link/introduction/#composing-a-link-chain). I edited the question for clarity. I don't believe any of that has [changed with v3](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration). `ApolloLink` is exported by `@apollo/client`, `setContext` is exported by `@apollo/link-context`

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I was wondering since I saw `UriOperation` as a possible means to construct the `HttpLink` `uri`.

Comment: Not sure where in the docs you are referring to. I don't see any mention of `UriOperation` anywhere

Comment: Thank you @DanielRearden, I marked your answer as the correct one since it is so indeed, and posted the un-related Typescript question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100960/typescript-variable-being-used-before-assigned

Comment: @Sammy Looks like you got an answer there already. FWIW, make sure you're using `uri`, not `endpoint` since that's the property HttpLink looks for inside the context.

Comment: Just fyi, as i've been doing something similar. I've not been able to currently return `async` functions to setContext so this won't work. If i do figure out whats up I'll be sure to post the solution.