# Typescript variable being used before assigned

Tags: single-page-application, apollo, auth0, react-apollo, apollo-client

As per instructions followed [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/api/link/apollo-link-context/#caching-lookups), I'm trying to cache my endpoint URL and token from Auth0 before constructing my Apollo client:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, from, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/link-context';
import { useAuth0 } from './auth/AuthContext';

const App: React.FC = () => {
 const { isLoading, getTokenSilently, getIdTokenClaims } = useAuth0();

 if (isLoading) return <Loader />;

 let endpoint: string;
 let token: string;
 const contextLink = setContext(async () => {
  if (!token) {
   token = await getTokenSilently();
  }
  if (!endpoint) {
   endpoint = await getIdTokenClaims()['https://example.com/graphql_endpoint'];
  }

  return { endpoint, token };
 });

 /**
  * TODO: check for autorization error and remove token from cache
  * See: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/api/link/apollo-link-context/
  */

 const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: from([
   contextLink,
   new HttpLink({
    uri: endpoint || '',
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
   })
  ])
 });

 return (
  <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
   <div />
  </ApolloProvider>
 );
};

export default App;
```

I'm getting the error TS2454 (variable is used before being assigned) for both `endpoint` and `token` above. Any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: I am not familiar with this type of code, but is it possible it is reaching `return { endpoint, token };` before the token and endpoint are set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring both `endpoint` and `token` as variables, but not initializing them to anything before checking them inside of setContext.

```
    let endpoint: string;
    let token: string;
    const contextLink = setContext(async () => {
        if (!token) {
            token = await getTokenSilently();
        }
        if (!endpoint) {
            endpoint = await getIdTokenClaims()['https://example.com/graphql_endpoint'];
        }

        return { endpoint, token };
    });
```

Try setting default values:

```
let endpoint: string = "";
let token: string = "";
```